# Python: is it faster to query clean string value from a db column or cleanup the string on the view/template?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a City model and fixture data with list of cities, and currently doing cleanups for URL on view and template before loading them. So I do below in a template to have a URL like this: http://newcity.domain.com.

```
<a href="http://{{ city.name|lower|cut:" " }}.{{ SITE_URL}}">
```

The actual city.name is "New City"

Would it be better if I stored already cleaned data (newcity) in a new column (short_name) on MySQL db and just use city.short_name on templates and views?

Comment: you should consider writing a custom tag if you end up doing that a lot

Answer (score 1):

This seems very opinion-oriented.  Is it faster?  The only way to know for sure is to measure.  Is it faster to a degree that you care about?  Probably not.  In any event, it's better not to make schema design decisions based on performance unless you've observed measurably bad performance.

All other things being equal, it is generally best to store the data in different columns.  It's easier to join it in controller or template code than it is to separate it out into its pieces.

Answer (score 0):

storing the short name in a MySQL database requires I/O. I/O is always slow, for such an easy transormation of data, it should be faster to keep it, like it is and avoid I/O to a database.

If you really want to know the difference, use timeit (https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), probably accessing a database is much slower.

Comment: the thing is that I already have City object in many of my views and I figured if I just create an additional column for that I'll just call it from the variable...

Comment: depennds on whether you need the additional information of your city object. If you already have all information in place (the city names, which needs to be transformed), accessing your database just for that task isn't worth the I/O.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, if you have a fixed amount of cities in a list, just make them hardcoded (unless you have lots of cities that will actually put some stress on your server's resources - but I don't think that it's the case here), otherwise - you must use some type of persistent store for the cities and a database will come handy.

Comment: I have around 900 cities in the database but they are all fixed.